# Preg_match/Preg_replace in php for matching pattern and replacing it in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace value in string with XXX

**input:**

```
insert into employees values('shrenik', 555, NULL)
```

**output:**

```
insert into employees values('XXX', XXX, NULL)
```

I tried this: `([0-9]|\'.*\')`

I want to match first for `insert into` after that want to skip the string up to `(`. I already mentioned in the statement the pattern and output I required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$sql = 'insert into employees values(\'shrenik\', 555, NULL)';
$pattern = '~(?:\binsert into [^(]*\(|\G(?<!^),(?:\s*+NULL,)*)\s*+\K(\')?(?(1)[^\']*\'|(?!NULL\b)[^\s,)]*)~i';

$sql = preg_replace($pattern, '$1XXX$1', $sql);
```

**pattern details**

```
~                           # pattern delimiter
(?:                         # non capturing group: where the pattern is allowed to start
    \binsert into [^(]*\(   # after "insert to" until the opening parenthesis
  |                         # OR
    \G(?<!^),               # after a precedent match if there is a comma
    (?:\s*+NULL,)*          # skip NULL values
)                         
\s*+                        # zero or more spaces
\K                          # reset all that was matched before from match result
(')?                        # optional capture group 1 with single quote 
(?(1)                       # IF capture group 1 exists:
    [^']*'                  # THEN matches all characters except ' followed by a literal '
  |                         # ELSE
    (?!NULL\b)[^\s,)]*      # matches all characters except spaces, comma, ) and the last NULL value
)                           # ENDIF
~i                          # closing pattern delimiter, case-insensitive
```

Comment: @user3292757: I have made several changes, and now it works (tested), do you tried the last version?

Comment: yes sir I have tried,its getting error. I am totally new to regex and I am trying the same online on http://www.compileonline.com/.written the same code that u have given

Comment: Hello sir, Need some more help from u...if my input string like this $sql = 'insert into employees values(nextval('public.scheduled_charges_id_seq' ),4633, 9085042, 116164, NULL,2522); result is not expected as I required. can u please update the same.I want otput like this $sql = 'insert into employees values(nextval('XXX' ),XXX, XXX, XXX, NULL, XXX);